# Flex DataGrid with Button with Skin

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex-spark

Try as I may, I am not able to skin a spark Button, when I place the button within a spark dataGrid. I am constrained to using the halo theme.

I have created the button renderer in a separate mxml file; I have separate buttons outside the dataGrid that show the skin correctly, so I am sure that there is nothing wrong with the skin. The whole point of this is to use the same skin inside the dataGrid as outside

The following code shows the same behavior that I am seeing; in this case the renderer is created in line. It seems like the skinClass is not respected.   Or is there another way to do it.

```
<s:DataGrid id="dg" width="500" dataProvider="{employees2}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <s:Button label="Press Me"
                                      top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
                                      skinClass="MyButtonSkin" />
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </GridColumn>   
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

In file MyButtonSkin.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
         minWidth="21" minHeight="21" 
         alpha.disabled="0.5">

<fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
    /** 
     * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
     */
    [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    ]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    <![CDATA[         
        /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
        For button, the graphics are colorized but the label is not. */
        static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay"];

        /** 
         * @private
         */     
        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }  

    ]]>        
</fx:Script>

<!-- states -->
<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" />
    <s:State name="down" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<!-- layer 2: fill -->
<!--- @private -->
<s:Rect id="fill" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="10">
    <s:fill>
        <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xFAFAFA" 
                             color.over="0xBBBDBD" 
                             color.down="0xAAAAAA" 
                             alpha="0.85" />
            <s:GradientEntry color="0x808080" 
                             color.over="0x9FA0A1" 
                             color.down="0x929496" 
                             alpha="0.85" />
        </s:LinearGradient>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<!-- layer 8: text -->
<!--- @copy spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase#labelDisplay  -->
<s:Label id="labelDisplay"
         textAlign="center"
         maxDisplayedLines="1"
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1" verticalAlign="middle">
</s:Label>

</s:SparkButtonSkin>
```

Comment: What is more exactly wrong there ? size / position ?

Comment: `when I place the button within a spark dataGrid. I am constrained to using the halo theme` That's not true. You should probably be using [GridItemRenderer](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/gridClasses/GridItemRenderer.html) though.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  This is a small part of a large project which was created using mx and the halo theme; that's where the constraint comes in.  Slowly I will be able to  move from mx:halo to spark:spark, but for now they must co-exist.  And the itemRenderer was a typo - which I have now corrected.

Comment: The aim of this is just to get rounded corners on the button in the grid, plus some font detail.  It just doesn't look like a button when in the dataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that scaling the button to the size of the grid item does not size the corner radius.

I ended up with a button 200x200 pixels with a corner radius of 6 pixels; it just couldn't be seen. I upped the value to 25 and now I can see it